# How to continue execution after 1 scenario gets failed in Karate. Already tried with try catch but no luck

Tags: javascript, karate, karate-call-single

I am using karate and i have a problem statement like i want to continue execution even if a error/exception comes.

I am using Karate forEach for the same, below is the sample code which i am using:

- def fun =
  """
  function() {
  try {
  karate.forEach(fields, function(item) {
  karate.call('validations/Test.feature', {ffield : item});
  });
  }
  catch(error) {
  console.error('An Error Occured:',error);
  }
  }
  """

Here, I am executing a API, and providing fields to an API, Now when i provide fields with a test data file, and a field is not acceptable in the API, it get failed and execution gets stop and moving further for execution for other fields. Any way to handle this in karate?

I tried above Karate forEach with try catch but its not working